# resetting a stringstream

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

How do I "reset" the state of a stringstream to what it was when I created it?

```
int firstValue = 1;
int secondValue = 2;

std::wstringstream ss;

ss << "Hello: " << firstValue;

std::wstring firstText(ss.str());

//print the value of firstText here


//How do I "reset" the stringstream here?
//I would like it behave as if I had created
// stringstream ss2 and used it below.


ss << "Bye: " << secondValue;

std::wstring secondText(ss.str());

//print the value of secondText here
```

Answer (score 160, accepted):

This is the way I usually do it:

```
ss.str("");
ss.clear(); // Clear state flags.
```

Comment: Thanks; debugging someone else's C++ and needed this to sort out an access violation error they were getting due to not doing the .clear() method.  Worked fine on an intel box but puked every time on an AMD machine.

Comment: Unfortunately `clear` doesn't reset io manipulators.  Example failing test:

std::stringstream ss;
ss << "Hello" << std::setw(15) << "World" << std::setw(15);
reset(ss);
        
ss << "Hello World";
assert("Hello World" == buf.str()); // fails, picks up last std::setw

Answer (score 16):

I would do

```
std::wstringstream temp;
ss.swap(temp);
```

Edit: fixed the error reported by christianparpart and Nemo. Thanks.

PS: The above code creates a new stringstream object on the stack and swaps everything in `ss` with those in the new object.

Advantages:

1. It guarantees `ss` will now be in a fresh-new state.
2. The new object is created inline and on the stack, so that the compiler can easily optimize the code. At the end, it will be like resetting all `ss` internal data to initial state.

More:

1. Compared to assignment operator: STL swap methods can be faster than assignment operator in the cases where the new object has an allocated buffer in the heap. In such a case, assignment operator has to allocate the buffer for the new object, then it MAY need to allocate another buffer for the old object, and then copy the data from the new object's buffer to the old object's new buffer. It is very easy to implement a fast swap, which just swaps pointers of the buffers for example.
2. C++11. I have seen some implementation of move assignment operator that is slower than swap, although that can be fixed, but probably STL developer won't want to leave a moved object with a lot of data
3. `std::move()` doesn't guarantee the moved object is emptied. `return std::move(m_container);` doesn't clear m_container. So you will have to do

   auto to_return(std::move(m_container));
   m_container.clear();
   return to_return;

Which can't be better than

```
auto to_return;
m_container.swap(to_return);
return to_return;
```

because the latter guarantees it won't copy buffers.

So I always prefer `swap()` as long as it fits.

Comment: You should explain **why** you would do this. This code isn't terribly useful by itself.

Comment: While this answer may be correct, please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.

Comment: I like the solution. It's very short, and the same template works for practically all std datatypes.

Comment: This answer is not quite correct as you may not bind to a temporary, that is, you create a temporary variable to swap the newly (temporarily) created empty string stream with the existing "ss" one. Not allowed.

Comment: Doesn't this incur all the overhead of constructing a locale, which resetting the stringstream is supposed to avoid?

Comment: @trapni the local variable is not a temporary variable.

Comment: @caps that's true.

Comment: Note that stringstream::swap() is not available prior to C++11.

Comment: Why I get `error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<wchar_t>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::wstringstream {aka std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<wchar_t>}’` (using GCC 5.4.0 with std=c++11)

Comment: swap will reset previous std::fixed etc.

Comment: a one liner: `std::stringstream{}.swap(ss);`

Comment: In current C++ i just use `ss = {};` to reset everything

Answer (score 7):

Building on answer above, we also need to reset any formatting. In all we are resetting the buffer contents, the stream state flags, and any formatting to their defaults when a new std::stringstream instance is constructed.

```
void reset(std::stringstream& stream)
{
    const static std::stringstream initial;
    
    stream.str(std::string());
    stream.clear();
    stream.copyfmt(initial);
}
```

Comment: The call to `stream.cpyfmt(initial)` will reset the locale of `stream` to match the locale of `initial`, according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/copyfmt).  So imbuing `initial` with a particular locale beforehand may be necessary if the goal is to reset `stream` without changing its locale.  I do not know whether doing this is more performant than creating a new ostringstream and imbuing it with a locale each time.