# how to reuse stringstream

Tags: c++, file, parsing, text, stringstream

These threads do NOT answer me:

[resetting a stringstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623650/)

[How do you clear a stringstream variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731/)

```cpp
std::ifstream file( szFIleName_p );
if( !file ) return false;

// create a string stream for parsing

std::stringstream szBuffer;

std::string szLine;     // current line
std::string szKeyWord;  // first word on the line identifying what data it contains

while( !file.eof()){

    // read line by line

    std::getline(file, szLine);

    // ignore empty lines

    if(szLine == "") continue;

    szBuffer.str("");
    szBuffer.str(szLine);
    szBuffer>>szKeyWord;
```

`szKeyword` will always contain the first word, `szBuffer` is not being reset. I can't find a clear example anywhere on how to use stringstream.

New code after answer:

```cpp
...
szBuffer.str(szLine);
szBuffer.clear();
szBuffer>>szKeyWord;
...
```

Ok, thats my final version:

```cpp
std::string szLine;     // current line
std::string szKeyWord;  // first word on the line identifying what data it contains

// read line by line

while( std::getline(file, szLine) ){

    // ignore empty lines

    if(szLine == "") continue;

    // create a string stream for parsing

    std::istringstream szBuffer(szLine);
    szBuffer>>szKeyWord;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reuse an ostringstream?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624260/how-to-reuse-an-ostringstream)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You didn't `clear()` the stream after calling `str("")`. Take another look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731/in-c-how-do-you-clear-a-stringstream-variable), it also explains why you should reset using `str(std::string())`. And in your case, you could also reset the contents using only `str(szLine)`.

If you don't call `clear()`, the flags of the stream (like `eof`) wont be reset, resulting in surprising behaviour ;)

Comment: dammit, I saw a thread saying clear just clears error flags..wtf man..can you explain me why I need both ? using just clear seems to work..?

Comment: These are related. If you don't call `clear()`, the stream will think its still in the `eof` state.

Comment: So clear important task on reset is putting the seek pointer (whatever it is called) at the beginning again? In the end, thats what I need: szBuffer.str(szLine);szBuffer.clear();

Comment: Its not about the seek pointer, its about the whole state of the stream. And yes, in your case you can simply "overwrite" the previous content like that.

Comment: Any chance youd be able to explain how not calling clear make it outputs a string from the previous content? I mean, that monster is holding all the strings allways?

Comment: This doesn't actually work reliably.  You also need to reset any formatting flags to the default.  Including those you don't know about, because they were allocated by a call to `std::ios_base::xalloc()` behind your back.

Answer (score 10):

It depends what you're doing with it.  It's generally easier to just
create a new `istringstream` or `ostringstream`.  To "reset" a stream,
you have to clear its buffer, clear any error flags, reset any
formatting flags, plus the precision and fill, re`imbue` it with the
original locale, and not forget any extended formatting information
generated with a value returned from `xalloc`.  In sum, impossible to
get correct.

And while I'm at it, your loop is wrong, and will probably result in the
last line being processed twice.  `file.eof()` only has a usable meaning
after the input has failed (and even then, it's not 100% reliable).
What you want is:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( file, line ) ) {
    if ( !line.empty() ) {
        std::istringstream buffer( line );
        //  ...
    }
}
```

(Actually, you probably want to trim trailing white space from the line
before the test for empty.)

Comment: I love how there's a lot of resources out there explaining all those very obvious std information out there, in an organized and well documented way, not

Comment: I could swear there was a committee member in a video claiming people were getting bad performance with streams because they were using them incorrectly by recreating them in loops instead of reusing references to them. I feel my life is a lie.

Comment: How about moving the buffer out of the old stringstream, then creating a fresh stringstream, using the old buffer? That way, you would reset everything, but reuse the storage. I tentatively think the methods added in C++20 allow this.

Comment: Having spent a few minutes playing, this seems to work: `std::stringstream ss; /* use ss */ std::string buffer = std::move(ss.rdbuf()->str()); buffer.resize(0); ss = std::stringstream(std::move(buffer));`? Not sure if this actually reuses the allocation, though!

Answer (score 3):

ss is stringstream.  Use

- first step:  ss.clear();
- second step: ss.str("");

to reuse the stringstream -- completely clear the string stream.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, it is easier to create a new `istringstream` or `ostringstream` instead of resetting the same ones.

However, if you do want to resent them:

- Resent flags of the stream (to avoid unexpected behavior) using `clear ()`.
- While you can correct the contents of your `stringstream` using `str ("")`, for efficiency purposes we might prefer `str(std::string())`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the stream in a class member, 
use `unique_ptr<stringstream>`, 
then just `reset(new stringstream(...))` to reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a config file.

```
par1=11
par2=22
```

codes:

```
std::string line, strpar1, strpar2;
int par1, par2;
std::ifstream configfile("config.cfg");

std::getline(configfile, line);    // first line to variable "line"
std::istringstream sline(line);
while (std::getline(sline, strpar1, '='));
par1 = std::stoi(strpar1);  // par1 get 11

bool b = sline.eof(); // true

std::getline(configfile, line);    // second line to variable "line"
sline.clear();    //
sline.str(line);    // reuse "sline"

b = sline.good();  // true  // goodbit is zero, indicating that none of the other bits is set.
b = sine.fail();  // false
b = sline.bad();  // false
b = sline.eof(); // false

while (std::getline(sline, strpar2, '='));
par2 = std::stoi(strpar2);  // par2 get 22
```

[goodbit is zero, indicating that none of the other bits is set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/basic_ios/clear/)