# How to avoid use of std::stringstream.str() and std::stringstream.clear() while reusing std::stringstream variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, googletest, stringstream

I've overloaded `operator<<` like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, SomeClass C){ 
//SomeClass is the class to be represented with operator overloading
os << "{ ";
os << C.getPropertyA() << " ";
os << C.getPropertyB() << " }";
//getPropertyA(), getPropertyB():functions of 'SomeClass' that return std::string
return os;
}
```

Now I'm using *googletest* to test `operator<<` overloading like this:

```
SomeClass C1;
SomeClass C2;
.
.
std::stringstream ss;
std::string str;

//First test
ss << C1;
std::getline(ss, str);
EXPECT_EQ("<some expected value>", str); // googletest test

//Second test
ss.str("");ss.clear(); //Mandatory if 'ss' need to be reused
ss << C2;
std::getline(ss, str);
EXPECT_EQ("<some expected value>", str); // googletest test
.
.
//Some more use 'ss' follows
```

Now the problem is everytime I add a new test I need to add `ss.str("");ss.clear();` before the test, apparently to empty *stream* and *clear* error state. This repetitive call of two `std::stringstream` functions makes me think I'm doing something wrong.

Hence I primarily need help with:

- How to reuse `std::stringstream` variable 'ss' without calling `ss.str("");ss.clear();` again and again OR
- Best alternative to implement test for overloaded `operator<<` using *googletest*.

Comment: You don't need to call both str() and clear().  Both calls do the same thing.  Or or the other is enough for what you want to do.  I don't think using a separate stringstream variable will bring any readability to your code.  using either str("") or clear() (my personal choice) makes yuour intent quite clear, and is more efficient that creating a new stringstream from scratch.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112259/how-to-reuse-stringstream) the accepted answer says there's a need to call clear() even after calling str(""). For me using only str("") is working fine though.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Also using only `clear()` is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to `getline` from string stream either as you can access underlying storage directly. The simpler approach would be to create new `stringstream` for each test:

```
//First test
{
    SomeClass C1;
    .
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << C1;
    EXPECT_EQ("<some expected value>", ss.str()); // googletest test
}

//Second test
{
    SomeClass C2;
    .
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << C2;
    EXPECT_EQ("<some expected value>", ss.str()); // googletest test
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out redundant use of `getline()`. I'm sticking with @MichaëlRoy 's suggestion for now.