# istringstream split_string(line) how to update the split_string while changing line without using while loop?

Tags: c++, sstream

```
line = "hello 2021"
istringstream split_string(line);
```

was a useful code to get the values from a string, i.e.

```
split_string>>str>>temp_double;
```

However, suppose that the value of line was changed, i.e.

```
line="hello world"
```

,and one wanted to write the following code with the updated value of line.

```
split_string>>str1>>str2;
```

How to update split_string so that it streamed the updated value of line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to reuse stringstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112259/how-to-reuse-stringstream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the C++20 standard `std::istringstream` [now has an `str()` method that allows replacing the contents of its internal buffer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/str). This functionality is not available in C++17 or earlier.

Before C++20 the closest alternative would be to use `std::stringstream` instead of `std::istringstream` and use `<<` to put stuff into the string stream that can be read back out.

CORRECTION: it possible to use `str()` to set the contents of `std::istringstream` prior to C++20, so this is the simplest solution.

Comment: An `istringstream::str()` overload that allows replacing the buffer has been around for a long time ([demo](https://ideone.com/H3QuaN)). What was added in C++20 are just new overloads for handling custom allocators, and rvalue references.