# c++ stringstream invalidated string pointer

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I have an `stringstream`, pushing to it in an iteration. After casting its content to an `int` object, it never changes after that. I think it changes but `instance.str()` is pointing to an invalidated place in which the string is not there anymore.

```
bool h = 1;
stringstream ss;
for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
{
    if(input[i] != ':')
    {
        cout << "input:  " << input[i] << endl;
        ss << input[i];
        cout << "ss:  " << ss.str() << endl;
    }
    else
        if(h)
        {
            ss >> hour;
            ss.str(string());
            h = 0;
        }   
}
```

in this loop, after the satisfaction of the condition( `h` being `true`), the stream's content is casting to an `int`. till this moment everything works fine but after this moment, `ss.str()` returns an empty `string`.

was my guess about invalidated string pointer right? if yes, what is the reason? if no, what is the reason of this behavior?

**UPDATE:**
I changed the sources code because the previous version was the way I handled the issue by this trick:

```
stringstream a(ss.str());
a >> hour;
ss.str(string());
```

Comment: Why do you have that addtitional `string()` in the second to last line?

Comment: @niklasfi to clear the content.

Comment: Maybe this solves your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623650/resetting-a-stringstream . Anyway, you should post a compilable piece of code. Maybe your error comes from somewhere else.

Comment: @Rémi yeah, that solved the problem. tnx. but I was curious about the reason.

Comment: I added an answer. You can also check that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731/in-c-how-do-you-clear-a-stringstream-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this line:

```
ss >> hour;
```

sets the eof bit of your stream because you reached the end of the string. When the eof bit is set, then the stream does not work any more. So you have to clear it after setting the empty string:

```
ss.str(string())
ss.clear()
```