# Can't output my whole file, premature exit by inputFile.eof()

Tags: c++, getline, sstream

```
if(inputFile.is_open()){
        while(!inputFile.eof()){
            getline(inputFile, line);
            ss << line;
                while(ss){
                ss >> key;
                cout << key << " ";
                lineSet.insert(lineNumber);
                concordance[key] = lineSet;
            }
            lineNumber++;
        }   
    }
```

For some reason, the while loop is kicking out after the first iteration and only displays the first sentence of my input file. The rest of the code works fine, I just can't figure out why it thinks the file has ended after the first iteration.

Thanks

Comment: while(!inputFile.eof()){

Comment: I'm sorry I have to share this, but dyslexia set it and I read this as "cant output my whole life" and was really curious as to why someone would want to do that :)

Comment: Reopened: although the `eof` use is wrong, it's not the main problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should be reading the file without using `eof` , as  πάντα ῥεῖ notes (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) for explanation):

```
while( getline(inputFile, line) )
{
    // process the line
}
```

Note that the preceding `if` is not necessary either.

The main problem , assuming `ss` is a `stringstream` you defined earlier, comes from the logic:

```
ss << line;
while(ss){
    // stuff
}
```

The `while` loop here only exits when `ss` fails. But you never reset `ss` to be in a good state. So although your outer loop does read every line of the file,  all of the lines after the first line never generate any output.

Instead you need to [reset the stringstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623650/resetting-a-stringstream) each time:

```
ss.clear();
ss.str(line);
while (ss) {
    // stuff
}
```