# Stringstream clearing trouble

Tags: c++, string, stl, stringstream

I am using `stringstream` for converting string of numerals to an integer. I don't know why followed code isn't working. Can someone explain to me why I am always getting equal values of the tmp variable?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
    std::ifstream input("input.txt");
    std::ofstream output("output.txt");
    std::string str = "", line;
    std::stringstream ss;
    int tmp;
    while (std::getline(input, line)) {
        for (int i = 0, l = line.size(); i < l; i++) {
            if (isdigit(line[i]))
                str += line[i];
        }
        ss << str;
        // gets int from stringstream
        ss >> tmp;
        output << str << ' ' << tmp << std::endl;
        str = "";
        // stringstream clearing
        ss.str("");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [resetting a stringstream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623650/resetting-a-stringstream)

Comment: @inetknght with ss.clear() it works. But why?

Comment: [Don't use while(!input.eof())](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). Instead, change the loop to `while (std::getline(input, line)) {`

Comment: @NikitaShelimov `clear()` resets the position indicator and any error flags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After

```
ss >> tmp;
```

`ss` is at EOF. None of the reads after that work. You can add a line

```
ss.clear();
```

after

```
ss.str("");
```

to clear its internal state. It will start to work. I used an `if` statement to test the hypothesis.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
    std::ifstream input("input.txt");
    std::string str = "", line;
    std::stringstream ss;
    int tmp;
    while (std::getline(input, line)) {
        for (int i = 0, l = line.size(); i < l; i++) {
            if (isdigit(line[i]))
                str += line[i];
        }
        ss << str;
        // gets int from stringstream
        ss >> tmp;
        std::cout << str << ' ' << tmp << std::endl;
        str = "";
        // stringstream clearing

        if (ss.eof())
        {
           std::cout << "ss is at eof\n";
        }

        ss.str("");
        ss.clear();

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To reset the `std::stringstream` you must first set the contents of the buffer with [`std::basic_stringstream::str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str) and then reset the input position with [`std::basic_istream::seekg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg), giving

```
ss.str(str);
ss.seekg(0);
ss >> tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to your approach on having to clear the `stringstream` at each iterate as @R Sahu mentioned, you can declare `std::stringstream ss` inside the while loop. This way, you destroy the variable at the end of each iterate and create a new one each time the while loop is executed.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input("input.txt");
    std::ofstream output("output.txt");
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(input, line))
    {
        std::string str;
        std::stringstream ss;
        int tmp;

        for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
        {
            if (isdigit(line[i]))
                str += line[i];
        }
        ss << str;
        // gets int from stringstream
        ss >> tmp;
        output << str << " " << tmp << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```